# Populating functional components representing SVG from array of Objects

Tags: reactjs, svg, methods, next.js, server-side-rendering

I tried to populate products cart with svg icons (functional components)"

*/BusinessCards.svg

```
function BusinessCards(props) {
  const {fill} = props; 
  return (
    <svg width={100} height={90} viewBox="0 0 100 90" >
      <path
        fill={fill}
        stroke="red"
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeMiterlimit={10}
        d="M95.5 64.5a5 5 0 01-5 5h-80a5 5 0 01-5-5v-40a5 5 0 015-5h80a5 5 0 015 5v40z"
      />
      <path
        fill="none"
        stroke="red"
        strokeWidth={2}
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        strokeMiterlimit={10}
        d="M24.26 29.322c1.725 2.828.484 5.862-2.343 7.588a6 6 0 11-6.25-10.244c1.563-.952 2.942-1.235 4.556-.704"
      />
      <path
        fill="none"
        stroke="#999"
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeMiterlimit={10}
        d="M34 31.5h4M44 31.5h18M57 41.5h29M44 47.5h42M21 54.5h19M21 60.5h28M15 60.5h0M15 54.5h0"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}
export default BuissnessCard
```

Simple api to provide data from array of objects
*/actions.js

```
 import BusinessCards from "@/components/UX/BusinessCards.js";
 import Flyers from "@/components/UX/Flyers.js";
       const PRODUCTS = [
          {
            icon: BuisnessCards,
            product: 'buisnessCards',
            id: 1,
            href: '/polygrafy/[product]',
            label: 'buisness cards',
            as: '/polygrafy/buisnessCards'
          },
          {
            icon: Flyers,
            product: 'flyers',
            id: 2,
            href: '/polygrafy/[product]',
            label: 'flyers',
            as: '/polygrafy/flyers'
          },


            export const getProducts = () => {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(PRODUCTS )
                reject('Cannot fetch data!')
            }, 50)
        })
      }
```

and finally my page 
*/index.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getProducts } from "@/actions/";

const Home = (props) => {
  const { products } = props;
  return (
           <ul>
              {products.map((product) => (
                <li
                  key={product.id}  
                >
                  <Link
                    href={product.href}
                    as={product.as}
                  >
                    <a>
                      <Component name={product.icon} fill='#ffffff'/>        
                      {product.label}
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
)
export default Home;

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const products = await getProducts();
  return {
    products,
  };
};
```

After running this code i get the error"

> Server Error TypeError: inst.render is not a function This error
>   happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed
>   in the terminal window.

My questions is: how to feeding svg functional components to my website?

Comment: You haven't shown where you call `inst.render()` i.e. the cause of error. Please make the code minimally reproducible.

Comment: Never used here inst.render() method, i am bit confused too about this error. Console show me res.status 500, parhaps i should not using Component to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use React.createElement(el, props, children)

Check out official doc here https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

In your case simply replace your icon component with that :

```
{React.createElement(product.icon, { fill : '#ffffff'})}
```

Comment: This is good solution for static page rendering, it works perfectly when i moved Products array to react page. Thank you Sir very much.

Comment: You're welcome
In fact, it's just a React trick to render custom Component
It has nothing to see with Next SSG/SSR deep features